# Can't add ICS file to iCal CalDAV account

Tags: mac, calendar.app, ics, caldav

Using Snow Leopard (10.6.4) I'm unable to add an ICS file received through Mail.app to a CalDAV account in iCal. Double clicking the file will open iCal but the option to add the event doesn't appear. The CalDAV account is a Google Apps hosted calendar.

Is this a bug, limitation or by design?

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue. Solution:

– select the calendar in iCal
– go to file=>Import…=>Import…
– navigate to the ics file
– a pop-up dialog asks you which calendar you want to import the event to.